# PHP Merging two Object Arrays / after redirect losing second part

Tags: php

I have created a login system that uses User (class) in that class I am setting data object. However there I am pulling from two different tables and merging the results together. I did the var_dump inside my login method that shows me all the correct information just before my RETURN statement.

However once login completes and I get redirected to my index.php page, I only can access User object data from the first table and MERGE gets lost.

What could be the problem?

Here is some of my code:

**INDEX**

```
$user = new User();
if($user->isLoggedIn()){
?>
<p>Hello <a href="#"><?php 
var_dump($user->data());
if(escape($user->data()->first_name) === NULL){
    echo escape($user->data()->username);
} else{
    echo escape($user->data()->username);
}?></a></p>
```

**LOG IN**

```
            $user = new User();
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'));
            if($login){
                Redirect::to('index.php');
```

**USER CLASS**

```
// Login function
public function login($username = NULL , $password = NULL){
    $user = $this->find($username);
    if($user){
        if(password_verify($password, $this->data()->password)){                
            // GRAB THE ID of user for pulling info from the personal
            $userId = $this->_data->id;
            $personal = $this->_db->get('personal', array('id', '=', $userId));
            $this->_data = (object) array_merge((array)$this->data(),(array) $personal->first());
           // VAR DUMP HERE SHOWS ALL CORRECT INFO
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}// End Login

// Find user
private function find($user = NULL){
    if($user){
        $field = (is_numeric($user))?'id':'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));
        $u = $data->first();        
        if($data->count()){
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
} // End FIND
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Added:
**Constructor**

```
$this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

        if(!$user){
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)){
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                if($this->find($user)){
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = TRUE;
                }else{}
            }
        }else {$this->find($user);}
```

Comment: Are you working in a framework?

Comment: Oh ok nice, it looks like framework material.  Great job.

Comment: What i did notice when I do var_dump is that inside the User class it shows Object #6 but when I dump it on Index shows Object #9 ... Not sure if that makes any sense to anyone..

Comment: Your mean is you miss `(array) $personal->first()`? Have you try to `error_log` this?

Comment: I am missing (array) $personal->first() this part on the Index page but not inside the User Class when I var_dump there where I am merging it works fine

Comment: You are creating a new `User` object at the start of your login, and at the start of your index page – so of course those are different instances, how did you expect anything else? And where is your constructor for that object, and what does it do? (And `data` method seems to be missing also.)

Comment: Constructor checks if the object exists and if it doesn't it creates new one

Comment: @CBroe is right. And show the constructor.

Comment: Am little confused with the variables / object instants you use. In constructor, if user is logged in you call a function `find` which stores user information in a variable `$this->_data` and in index file you refer to a function `$user->data()`. If these don't make any big difference. I see another problem where in `find` function you probably have to merge the data again similar to what you do in `login` function and store it to `$this->_data` if `$user->data()` returns this value.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I went trough it step by step to figure out where I am losing data, it turns out once I redirect I am calling the constructor but not the login to get the data.

So i have relocated the code where I am merging the Object Arrays into the constructor and it all works now fine.

Here is the code:

```
public function __construct($user = null){
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

        if(!$user){
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)){
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                if($this->find($user)){
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = TRUE;
                    // GRAB THE ID of user for pulling info from the personal
                    $userId = $this->_data->id;
                    $personal = $this->_db->get('personal', array('id', '=', $userId));
                    $this->_data = (object) array_merge((array)$this->data(),(array) $personal->first());
                }else{logout();}
            }
        }else {
            $this->find($user);
        }
    }
```

So the trick was in the constructor, if the user exists it was calling the FIND user function (and I have added merge inside the login function).

Hope this helps someone else, also thanks everyone for trying I truly appreciate it.